# How to do a multi select list-view and get the selected item?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a list view with car brands. I am doing a basic survey app that the user needs to select all that applies. So far I can only do is to get one selected item based on the tutorial online. Is there a way to have a multi-select list view and get the value? or What are the other things I can do to achieve this?

```
var listView = new ListView();
listView.ItemsSource = new string[]
{
  "Honda",
  "Toyota",
  "Ford",
  "Tesla"
};
```

Comment: Add a Checkbox kind of control using a button and on the basis of that you can just iterate through that property to find which controls are selected

Comment: @G.hakim can you show me how? I still learning the basic of list view

Comment: Can you add the model that you are using and then maybe I can come up with something?

Comment: @G.hakim I just used this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Comment: Added an answer below with understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The First thing you need to do is make a generic something as below:

```
public class SelectableData<T> 
{ 
  public T Data { get; set; }
  public bool Selected { get; set; } 
}
```

Next, you will want to create the ListView, that shows the data and the Switch.  In this example, my Data, just has Name and Description inside it. The wrapper, then contains the Selected Boolean.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" Margin="20">
<ListView.ItemTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
        <ViewCell> 
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10"> 
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> 
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"> 
                    <Label Text="{Binding Data.Name}"  /> 
                    <Label Text="{Binding Data.Description}" FontSize="10" /> 
                </StackLayout> 
                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" Grid.Column="1" /> 
            </Grid> 
        </ViewCell> 
    </DataTemplate> 
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then bind the ListView with something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<SelectableData<ExampleData>> DataList { get; set; }
```

Where ExampleData is something like:

```
 public class ExampleData
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

To get the selected item iterate through the `DataList` using a for each loop and check the Selected Property something like this:

```
foreach(var item in DataList)
{
   item.Selected // true if selected else false.
}
```

Comment: So how can i get the select items?

Comment: Oh yeah give me a minute

Comment: public class ExampleData is this a separate file or a class within the file? And how about this public class SelectableData<T>  a separate file or within the file also?

Comment: You can add it with example or separate that is fine and both of them are separate classes

Comment: Last question I am having a problem navigating to my tab page I am logging in and I used await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new TabbedPage()); to navigate to my tab page when I click the button that tab page shows nothing

Comment: Add that as another question with code and I can check that out if you put the link it here otherwise I would be speculating which I do not like to do I like to actually talk about the issue instead.

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I hope that is fine with you?

Comment: Thank you you have been a big help I will try what you posted I cant try right now because I can navigate properly to my tab page

Comment: Add that question and post a link here and tag me so I know and maybe I would have an answer for your issue

Comment: Here sir, I posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181779/navigating-to-tabbed-page

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto I am no sir please don't embarrass me, my name is Ali you can call me that

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't assign an array of strings to ItemsSource. Bind your ItemsSource to ObservableCollection. When you do that the list will be updated whenever you change the collection. For more info take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#data-binding).

Secondly, out of the box Xamarin.Forms doesn't provide you with an option to select multiple items. Though, you can do that following [these instructions](https://xamarinhelp.com/multiselect-listview-xamarin-forms/)