# Navigating to Tabbed Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a ContentPage(Login Page) that should navigate to my TabbedPage(TabPage). The problem is when I use the code:

> await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new
>   TabbedPage());

to navigate to my tab page is not displaying anything.

This is what I am seeing when I use the code above:
[image]

And this is what I am seeing when I set the Main Page:
[image]

Comment: I there a requirement for using a ModalPage? shouldn't you just use PushAsync if there isn't?

Comment: I tried using pushasync same result

Comment: Make sure the TabbedPage referred in your `PushModalAsync` is your TabbedPage and not the Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage otherwise it will be blank

Comment: @G.hakim you are right I made an error TabPage is the name of Page my naming convention is messed up

Comment: Added that as the answer Goodluck

Comment: @G.hakim sir can you help me I posted a new question I really dont know how to proceed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184331/multi-select-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason it is not working is that you are using the `Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage` in place of your own TabbedPage

Changing that should solve your issue,

Good luck revert if this does not work

I would suggest one more thing your Page naming convention should be different so that you do not confuse yourself and the compiler.

For Eg, if your page has a `TabbedPage` and your functionality for it is something like playing music and different tabs for different types of it then you name it as `MusicTabbedPage` for better understanding