# Multi-select Listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, multi-select

This is my list view it should contain the list of activities came from my SQLite database:

```
<ListView SeparatorVisibility="None" x:Name="lstActivity" HasUnevenRows="True">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <Frame StyleClass="lstframe" CornerRadius="0" BorderColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False">
                   <StackLayout StyleClass="lstContainer" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                       <Grid>
                           <Label StyleClass="lstActivityName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ActivityDescription}">
                               <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="Poppins-Regular.otf#Poppins-Regular"/>
                                     </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                           </Label>
                           <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" />
                       </Grid>
                   </StackLayout>
               </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Here is how I populate the list view this will return atleast five(5) activities:

```
public void Get_Activities()
{
   try
   {
       var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
       var conn = db.GetConnection();

       var getActivity = conn.QueryAsync<ActivityTable>("SELECT * FROM tblActivity WHERE Deleted != '1' ORDER BY ActivityDescription");
       var resultCount = getActivity.Result.Count;

       if (resultCount > 0)
       {
           var result = getActivity.Result;
           lstActivity.ItemsSource = result;
           lstActivity.IsVisible = true;
       }
       else
       {
           lstActivity.IsVisible = false;
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }
}
```

Selected item binding:

```
public class SelectData
{
   public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Get selected Items on click:

```
private void BtnClose_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (var x in result)
   {
      if (x.Selected)
      {
         // do something with the selected items
      }
 }
    }
```

I posted another question regarding on multi-select list view my problem is I don't know how to proceed when I use the answers given to me. How can I get the the selected values because I will save the selected values to my database?

Comment: you are binding the switch to your model, so to get the selected items just get the items in your model that are marked as selected

Comment: @Jason can you show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Switch` is bound to the `Selected` property of your model.  Just iterate (or use LINQ) to get the items that are selected.

```
// you need to maintain a reference to result
foreach(var x in result)
{
  if (x.Selected) 
  {
    // do something with the selected items
  }
}
```

LINQ

```
var selected = result.Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();
```

you will also need to have a class level reference to result

```
// you will need to change this to reflect the actual type of result
List<MyClass> result;

public void Get_Activities()
{
    ...
    result = getActivity.Result;
    ...
```

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: wherever you want to process the selected items

Comment: I updated my question I am getting an error when I get the selected item

Comment: "an error" is not a helpful description of the problem

Comment: The error is the name 'result' does not exist in the current context

Comment: as I said in my answer, `you need to maintain a reference to result`.  In your current code result is a local variable, you need to maintain a class level reference to it.

Comment: Sorry I am really newbie how can I do that?

Comment: simply declare result at a class level.  I can't be more specific because I don't know what the type of result is.  This is basic C#

Comment: see my expanded example

Comment: Thank you I will try it

Comment: What do I put in <MyClass>?

Comment: "you will need to change this to reflect the actual type of result" - what is the type of `result`?

Comment: I really dont get it sorry

Comment: `var result = getActivity.Result;` - what is the type of that result?  This is YOUR code?!?!  You should know this or be able to figure it out.  If I had to guess I'd say it's a `List<ActivityTable>` but I can't be sure.

Comment: Just to clarify what I will put inside <MyClass> is the class where the item source in my case it is ActivityTable

Comment: one question how can I check if the user hasn't selected anything?

Comment: result.Any(x => x.Selected) will be false if nothing is selected

Answer (score 0):

For multi-select Listview, I have wrote a working example in my blog. Hope this helps : https://androidwithashray.blogspot.com/2018/03/multiselect-list-view-using-xamarin.html?view=flipcard